# Accessing google spreadsheet through python

Tags: python, excel, google-sheets

I am trying to connect to my google sheet through python. Here is my code snippet.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import time
import gdata.spreadsheet.service

email = 'mymailid@gmail.com'
password = 'mypass'
spreadsheet_key = '1k7XK1FzGcdLdQXs8hfLn6pdWcNZiesmW6Y5eOdxtDwE'
worksheet_id = 'od6'
spr_client = gdata.spreadsheet.service.SpreadsheetsService()
spr_client.email = email
spr_client.password = password

try :
    spr_client.ProgrammaticLogin()
    print "Connected to spreadsheet"
except Exception as e : 
    print "Error connecting to spreadsheet !!! ERROR : ", e

dict = {}
dict['date'] = time.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
dict['time'] = time.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
print dict

try :
    entry = spr_client.InsertRow(dict, spreadsheet_key, worksheet_id)
    print "Data entered successfully"
except Exception as e :
    print "Could not fill the spreadsheet !!! ERROR : ", e
```

**1**. First off all I tried with my correct username and password but it throws an error `cElementTree.ParseError: mismatched tag: line 1254, column 4`
although my code is of just 30 lines.

**2.** I tried wrong username and password. It still shows `Connected to spreadsheet`.

**3.** On running `spr_client.InsertRow(dict, spreadsheet_key, worksheet_id)`, it is throwing error `Could not fill the spreadsheet ERROR :  mismatched tag: line 1254, column 4`

I have tried all this from [this](http://james-says.blogspot.in/2007/07/beginners-guide-for-google-spreadsheet.html)  link.

What could be the reason here for this topsy-turvy. Or I am wrong somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at `gspread` api, it's much more easy to use and Pythonic: https://github.com/burnash/gspread. I had a lot of troube using `gdata.spreadshet` until I found the other one.